# Разработка под Android, вопрос новичка о ресурсах

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, eclipse

Только начал программировать под Андроид, появилась небольшая проблемка.
Использую кусок программы

```
Drawable newImage;
newImage = getResources().getDrawable(_картинка_);
```

Необходимо, чтобы на место _*картинка*_ подставлялось "R.drawable.i", где i - некая переменная типа int. Как это написать, не используя case?

Comment: Сразу на ум пришла только рефлексия. Но что-то мне подсказывает лучше switch ... case

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что надо менять подход в корне.

В **res/drawable** - хранятся, скажем так, уникальные картинки, к каждому из которых надо обращаться поименно. Пытаться обращаться с ними чохом/массивом будет трудно. Будет либо огромный `swith-case`, либо некая хрень через рефлексию или еще чего похуже.

Я бы положил ваше множество картинок в **assets** и голову бы не грел. С картинками/файлами в **assets** можно спокойно обращаться почти как с файлами в файловой системе - засунуть их разом в массив, перенумеровать и все такое.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы написать добавление в массив предположим 1 картинки из assets и ее применение к некоему ImageView tempImage? Большое спасибо за ответ

UPD Уже нашел